# consulta Sql trazendo os produtos que estao com saldo zerado

Tags: sql

Tenho as tabelas :

```
Produto                Departamento        
=========              ========
Id_Prod                id_Departamento                                       
Descricao              Descricao     


Produto_Departamento
=====================
id_Prod
Id_Departamento
Saldo
```

Tendo o seguinte cenário, gostaria da ajuda de voces para desenvolver essa consulta.

Gostaria de trazer todos os produtos cujo a soma do saldo seja = 0. Lembrando que o produto poderá esta cadastrado em vários departamentos

Comment: Não seria somente dar um sum do saldo e agrupar por produto?

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está usando? Pro caso de uma query mais especifica, claro.

Answer (score 2):

Você não especificou muito bem, mas acredito que esse exemplo irá te ajudar:

```
select p.id_Prod, prod.Descricao from Produto_Departamento p
inner join Produto prod on prod.Id_Prod=p.Id_Prod
having sum(p.Saldo)>0
group by p.id_Prod,prod.Descricao
```

Comment: Mas essa query não traz os produtos, somente a soma.

Comment: Sim, é só ele fazer o join e trazer os produtos

Comment: Mas é justamente isso que ele pede na pergunta. Sugiro que adicione na resposta, assim ela atenderá a pergunta e fica completa :)

Comment: Ok, completei a resposta.